# submit code not working correctly

Tags: php, mysqli, statements

Well, i've created simple registration form, i mean its not registration, it should check if the user name exists in the database, but it doesnt work, i mean, it only shows $rows and doesnt check for username that well, always get This username does not exists, even if it does.

Names are stored as Firstname_Lastname, thats why i converted 2 strings into 1_2

```
if(isset($_POST['register_button']))
{       

    $name = clear($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = clear($_POST['lastname']);

    $createdname = sprintf("%s_%s", $name, $lastname);

    $escapename = mysqli_real_escape_string($createdname, $escapename);

    $email = clear($_POST['email']);
    $pass = clear($_POST['password']);
    $cpass = clear($_POST['confpassword']);

    $query = "SELECT Ime FROM Igraci WHERE Ime = '$escapename'";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($row)
    {
        echo 'Thsis name already exists print: '.$createdname.'';
        exit();
    }
    else if(!$row)
    {
        echo 'This name does not exists: '.$createdname.'';
        exit();
    }
}

if($_COOKIE['authorization'] == "ok")
{
    header ("Location:welcome.php");
    exit();
}


function clear($message)
{
   if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
   $message = addslashes($message);
   $message = strip_tags($message);
   $message = htmlentities($message);
   return trim($message);
}
```

Comment: try using mysqli_num_rows instead of mysqli_fetch_array to get the number of rows selected and check if $row is bigger than 0

Comment: They cant have same name because it is a game

Comment: Your clear function strips tags and removes beginning and trailing spaces.  But why transform with htmlentities?

Comment: Because i'm also using that in news system for html entities that are being inserted on adding news

Comment: Does anyone know, i've tried counting rows but not working:

http://pastebin.com/3ByvuP1d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your assignment:  $escapename = mysqli_real_escape_string($createdname,  $escapename); has the wrong parameters passed to mysqli_real_escape_string.  The first parameter should be your sql connection variable.  Otherwise you could just pass $createdname to the function like so:
   **$escapename = mysqli_real_escape_string($createdname);**
2. Since you just want to know if the name exists in the database you should use the suggestion in the comment from FareedMN and query for a count, then check if the count is >0.  You can use this query:
   **$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Igraci WHERE Ime = '$escapename'";**

Comment: Ok, so i've tried something like this but its not working, nor displaying the name
http://pastebin.com/xkvkvszA

Comment: Do you know ? it's like this now but its not working http://pastebin.com/3ByvuP1d

Comment: Is it at least getting into the if/else statement?  Are you seeing the first part where it says "Thsis name already exists print:" or "'This name does not exists:"?  (by the way 'This' in the if statement is misspelled)

Comment: Also you don't need the single quotes around '$createdname' in your query statement since you have the double quotes around the entire statement.